# Making an object "Throb"/Grow and Shrink

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

pretty new to WPF, but i've made a Surface app to get peoples attention in my office reception.

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2012/06/03/building-an-image-and-video-viewer-for-microsoft-surface-20-in-no-time-at-all

what I would like to do, is if people haven't touched the screen for a while (i'm already recording this with a timer), I want to make each of the objects in my app "Throb" one by one to get peoples attention.

Would i use a transform or a storyboard?

Comment: You would have a Storyboard altering the values of a ScaleTransform.  You just need to play with the Storyboard values to make it throb (AccelerationRatio, DecelerationRatio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up calling the following method on a timer:

```
void RunScaleAnimation(FrameworkElement e)
{

var storyboard = new Storyboard();
var easeOut = new BackEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut, Amplitude = 0.3 };

double startHeight = e.ActualHeight;
double startWidth = e.ActualWidth;

var growAnimationHOut = new DoubleAnimation(startHeight, startHeight * 1.05,
                                            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)) { AutoReverse = true };

var growAnimationWOut = new DoubleAnimation(startWidth, startWidth * 1.05,
                                            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)) { AutoReverse = true };

growAnimationHOut.EasingFunction = easeOut;
growAnimationWOut.EasingFunction = easeOut;

storyboard.Children.Add(growAnimationHOut);
storyboard.Children.Add(growAnimationWOut);

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimationWOut, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimationHOut, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty));

e.BeginStoryboard(storyboard);
}
```